# how do i know if Vc(0+) or Vc(0-) is zero?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, capacitance, transient

[image]

i mean like in this picture, why is Vc(0-) = 10 v? why isnt it =0? when do i decide that there exists a voltage there even though it was in steady state? im not completely getting it.

Comment: Well, there's a voltage source, right?

Comment: yeah

but wouldn't it being an open circuit affect it?

Comment: hint: at t=0, what's the voltage at the upper end of the capacitor?

Comment: Assume that $$V_c(0^{-})$$ is zero.  Compute the current through each resistor.  Note that Kirchoff's Current Law is violated.

Comment: Regarding the load resistor being in an open circuit, $$V_R(t) = 0 \;\; \forall t < 0$$ because of the open circuit.  But the capacitor is in a closed circuit for both switch positions.

Comment: so say that the switch was at position B for a long time, would the Vc(0) = 0 then? since its being discharged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple when split into two parts.

1. With the switch in the position shown you have the capacitor in parallel with the lower resistor of a potential divider. The capacitor will charge up to the potential divider voltage. All you have to do is calculate what that voltage is.
2. After the switch is thrown you have a simple C-R discharge. The time constant is given by \$ \tau = RC \$ and you should know (or learn if you don't) the following for a charge or discharge curve:

   - At t = 1τ the capacitor voltage will have reduced by 63%.
   - At t = 3τ the capacitor voltage will have reduced by 95%.
   - At t = 5τ the capacitor voltage will have reduced by 99%.

[image]

*Figure 1. RC discharge from 9 V. Source:[http://electronicsclub.info].*

So figure out the RC time constant and plot those three points and draw the curve with Y-axis from 0 to the voltage calculated in step 1 and the X-axis going from -2 to +10 s as instructed in the question.

Tip: use proper capitalisation and punctuation in your posts and comments. It makes you more credible and it's the right way to write.